# How to change MAMP configuration to run PHP?

Tags: php, macos, mamp

Mac os is new for me. I have recently installed MAMP on my MAC OS.I have placed my php project in

Applications/MAMP/htdocs

when i execute this code i got the URL as

```
   localhost:8888/
```

as the url says it is using port 8888 i don't want that 8888 on my url as there are various redirection on my project. So i tried by changing the port on
 MAMP------ prefrences-----imade it set default apace andMySql ports

but after ist when i restart the MAMP i find the url

```
    localhost/MAMP/?language=English
```

with the following error message :

Not Found

The requested URL /MAMP/ was not found on this server.

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try localhost:80 which is the default...

Comment: @pattyd There is no difference between http://localhost/ and http://localhost:80/

Comment: @pilsetnieks I know that, I was telling him to set the port to port 80 in the preferences (read my answer).

Comment: @pattyd but still not working, I want to show localhost without any port number

Comment: @pilsetnieks  but still not working, I want to show localhost without any port number

Comment: @user223887 As noted in my answer, I don't think you're having as many problems as you think you are. Does localhost not work

Comment: @user223887 if it is set to port 80, all you have to type is `localhost`... look at my answer!

Answer (score 0):

By default localhost will run on port 80.
 If your localhost runs on port 80, the only thing you have to type in to your browser is `localhost`. If you have to type `localhost:8888` then that means it is running on port `8888`! If you want to change this, open `httpd.conf` (your Apache config file) and scroll down to line 47, where it says `listen #`. Change that line to `listen 80`. Turn on your server (reboot may be needed) then open your browser and type `localhost`. 
I will be happy to give further help if needed!

Comment: the default port in MAMP is 8888. It will also change the config file when the preferences change so there is no need to change httpd.conf

Comment: Then just change the preferences to 80

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get implies that apache is running and it's on port 80. The error message states that the url /MAMP/ isn't valid, which if you've added your project is probably the case. There is a preference in MAMP that will get it to launch a sort of helper page when it starts, I think this is what you are seeing.
If you've copied you project into the htdocs you may need to modify the httpd.conf file located in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache` with your site specific details such as document root. Look for the section that starts with

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
```

Remember you need to restart the service for your changes to apply!

If it's you're still having problems have a look at the apache log files located `/Applications/MAMP/logs`